# Call command function from views.py

Tags: python, django

According to this `[article][1]`,
I made the `Command` class.

`myapp/management/commands/mycommand.py`

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def command_test(self):
        print("test command_test")
```

Now I want to call this command_test from `views.py` like this below...

Is it possible??

in `myapp/views.py`

```
def index(request):
    Command.command_test()
```

Comment: It is possible, but it is bad idea.
Better move code, common between management command and views to some common.py file as simple function and use it in both cases.

Comment: I see. thank you it's quite clear. I will make `service` or `library` (how can I call in django??), and use from both `views.py` and `command`